# How to add style to more than one img in the same css / div at the same time

Tags: html, css

Please may you help me. How do you target lots of imgs and use the same css for all instead of having to do them individually as I have done. Essentially what is the correct syntax to have the .jpg files in order. Thank you for your help and time!

```
   <style>
/*Image hover*/

 .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/published/h4.png?1489059309"]{
  -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
  transition: transform .7s ease !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  transform: scale(.9) !important;
}

 .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/published/h4.png?1489059309"]:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -o-transform:scale(1) !important;
  transform:scale(1) !important;
}

     .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h2_orig.png"]{
  -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
  transition: transform .7s ease !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  transform: scale(.9) !important;
}

 .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h2_orig.png"]:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -o-transform:scale(1) !important;
  transform:scale(1) !important;
}


         .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h1_orig.png"]{
  -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
  transition: transform .7s ease !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  transform: scale(.9) !important;
}

 .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h1_orig.png"]:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -o-transform:scale(1) !important;
  transform:scale(1) !important;
}


    .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h3_orig.png"]{
  -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
  transition: transform .7s ease !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  transform: scale(.9) !important;
}

 .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h3_orig.png"]:hover{
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -o-transform:scale(1) !important;
  transform:scale(1) !important;
}




</style>
```

Grim suggestion:

```
<style>
/*Image hover*/

 .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/published/h4.png?1489059309"],  .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h2_orig.png"], .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h1_orig.png"], .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h3_orig.png"], {
  -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
  transition: transform .7s ease !important;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
  transform: scale(.9) !important;
}

 .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/published/h4.png?1489059309"], .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h2_orig.png"], .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h1_orig.png"],  .wsite-image-border-none img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h3_orig.png"]:hover {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -moz-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -ms-transform:scale(1) !important;
  -o-transform:scale(1) !important;
  transform:scale(1) !important;
}

</style>
```

Not sure what Im missing

Comment: use same `class` for all

Answer (score 2):

Assiming you can't just add a class to the images, you can use commas.

So something like:

```
.wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/published/h4.png?1489059309"], .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h2_orig.png"], .wsite-image-border-none  img[src="/uploads/4/1/3/2/41323535/h3_orig.png"] {
      -webit-transition: -webkit-transform .7s ease !important;
      -moz-transition: -moz-transform .7s ease !important;
      -ms-transition: -ms-transform .7s ease !important;
      -o-transition: -o-transform .7s ease !important;
      transition: transform .7s ease !important;
      -webkit-transform: scale(.9) !important;
      -moz-transform: scale(.9) !important;
      -ms-transform: scale(.9) !important;
      -o-transform: scale(.9) !important;
      transform: scale(.9) !important;
    }
```

Or, better still, look into using something like SCSS to create your CSS files for you.

Comment: Thankyou for your time. And yes you are correct I cant add classes which is what id usually do, but its a CMS. Ive used the suggestion you gave me but hasnt worked yet. Im sure ive got a comma out of place. Thank you!